# Why symbols are not getting resolved

Tags: windows, windbg, symbols, crash-dumps

I have got a dump file from a client, however, I am not able to resolve the symbols which is causing issue when making sense of stack traces. Below is what I have done. Can you please advise what I am doing wrong here?

```
0:12> !sym -noisy
noisy mode - symbol prompts on

0:12> .symfix
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: cache*;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: cache*;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: cache*;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

0:12> .reload
..
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\743996EA223643DFA2C1AA9BFDDCFE502\ntdll.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\743996EA223643DFA2C1AA9BFDDCFE502\ntdll.pdb already cached

DBGHELP: ntdll - public symbols  
        C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\743996EA223643DFA2C1AA9BFDDCFE502\ntdll.pdb
..............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
.........................
Loading unloaded module list
.............
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\mscorlib.pdb\03EA52B254BD4C79B589768D49ED6C2D1\mscorlib.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\mscorlib.pdb\03EA52B254BD4C79B589768D49ED6C2D1\mscorlib.pdb already cached
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
DBGHELP: mscorlib_ni - public symbols  
        C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\mscorlib.pdb\03EA52B254BD4C79B589768D49ED6C2D1\mscorlib.pdb


0:12> k
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`05a6cd90 000007fe`2bd6b8c1 mscorlib_ni+0x468597
00000000`05a6ce20 00000001`91c67a70 0x000007fe`2bd6b8c1
00000000`05a6ce28 000007fe`890284c6 0x00000001`91c67a70
00000000`05a6ce30 000007fe`2bd6b8fd mscorlib_ni+0x4684c6
00000000`05a6cec0 00000001`91c78c98 0x000007fe`2bd6b8fd
00000000`05a6cec8 000007fe`890284c6 0x00000001`91c78c98
00000000`05a6ced0 000007fe`2bd6b8fd mscorlib_ni+0x4684c6
00000000`05a6cf60 00000001`91c78b90 0x000007fe`2bd6b8fd
00000000`05a6cf68 000007fe`890284c6 0x00000001`91c78b90
00000000`05a6cf70 000007fe`2bd6b8fd mscorlib_ni+0x4684c6
00000000`05a6d000 00000001`91c67a70 0x000007fe`2bd6b8fd
00000000`05a6d008 000007fe`890284c6 0x00000001`91c67a70
00000000`05a6d010 000007fe`2bd6b8fd mscorlib_ni+0x4684c6
00000000`05a6d0a0 00000001`91c67a70 0x000007fe`2bd6b8fd
00000000`05a6d0a8 000007fe`890284c6 0x00000001`91c67a70
00000000`05a6d0b0 000007fe`2bd6b8fd mscorlib_ni+0x4684c6
00000000`05a6d140 00000001`91c75348 0x000007fe`2bd6b8fd
00000000`05a6d148 000007fe`890284c6 0x00000001`91c75348
00000000`05a6d150 000007fe`2bd6b8fd mscorlib_ni+0x4684c6
00000000`05a6d1e0 00000001`91c67a70 0x000007fe`2bd6b8fd
00000000`05a6d1e8 000007fe`890284c6 0x00000001`91c67a70
00000000`05a6d1f0 000007fe`2bd6b8fd mscorlib_ni+0x4684c6
00000000`05a6d280 00000001`91c69eb0 0x000007fe`2bd6b8fd
00000000`05a6d288 000007fe`890284c6 0x00000001`91c69eb0
00000000`05a6d290 000007fe`2bd6b8fd mscorlib_ni+0x4684c6
00000000`05a6d320 00000001`91c67a70 0x000007fe`2bd6b8fd
00000000`05a6d328 000007fe`890284c6 0x00000001`91c67a70
00000000`05a6d330 000007fe`2bd6b8fd mscorlib_ni+0x4684c6
00000000`05a6d3c0 00000001`91c67a70 0x000007fe`2bd6b8fd
00000000`05a6d3c8 000007fe`890284c6 0x00000001`91c67a70
00000000`05a6d3d0 000007fe`2bd6b8fd mscorlib_ni+0x4684c6
00000000`05a6d460 00000001`91c67ba0 0x000007fe`2bd6b8fd
00000000`05a6d468 000007fe`890284c6 0x00000001`91c67ba0
00000000`05a6d470 000007fe`2bd6b8fd mscorlib_ni+0x4684c6
00000000`05a6d500 000007fe`2bc1aed8 0x000007fe`2bd6b8fd
00000000`05a6d508 000007fe`2b893680 0x000007fe`2bc1aed8
00000000`05a6d510 00000000`05a6d7b8 0x000007fe`2b893680
00000000`05a6d518 00000000`05a6d7b0 0x5a6d7b8
00000000`05a6d520 00000001`91af0110 0x5a6d7b0
00000000`05a6d528 00000001`00000000 0x00000001`91af0110
00000000`05a6d530 00000000`00000000 0x00000001`00000000
```

**EDIT**
As per Hans suggestion in comments below, here is the managed stack trace

```
0:12> !CLRStack
        Child SP               IP Call Site
0000000005a6cd90 000007fe89028597 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].Insert(System.__Canon, System.__Canon, Boolean)
0000000005a6ce20 000007fe2bd6b8c1 
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\System.Data.Entity.pdb\8F8E35EC731B4EE9B4811CB80EE790B41\System.Data.Entity.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\System.Data.Entity.pdb\8F8E35EC731B4EE9B4811CB80EE790B41\System.Data.Entity.pdb already cached

DBGHELP: System_Data_Entity - public symbols  
        C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\System.Data.Entity.pdb\8F8E35EC731B4EE9B4811CB80EE790B41\System.Data.Entity.pdb
System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6cec0 000007fe2bd6b8fd System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6cf60 000007fe2bd6b8fd System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6d000 000007fe2bd6b8fd System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6d0a0 000007fe2bd6b8fd System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6d140 000007fe2bd6b8fd System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6d1e0 000007fe2bd6b8fd System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6d280 000007fe2bd6b8fd System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6d320 000007fe2bd6b8fd System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6d3c0 000007fe2bd6b8fd System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6d460 000007fe2bd6b8fd System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6d500 000007fe2bd6b8fd System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessor.ApplyRulesToSubtree(System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.RuleProcessingContext, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Rule>>, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.Node, Int32)
0000000005a6d5a0 000007fe2bd635c0 System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.TransformationRules.Process(System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler, System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.TransformationRulesGroup)
0000000005a6d610 000007fe2bb67e40 System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.ProviderCommandInfo> ByRef, System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMap ByRef, Int32 ByRef, System.Data.Common.Utils.Set`1<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySet> ByRef)
0000000005a6d6b0 000007fe2bb6723b System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory, System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbCommandTree)
0000000005a6d850 000007fe2bb66ff8 System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(System.Data.Common.DbProviderManifest, System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbCommandTree)
0000000005a6d8a0 000007fe2bb66425 System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext, System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbQueryCommandTree, System.Type, System.Data.Objects.MergeOption, System.Data.Objects.Span, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2<System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter,System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression>>, System.Data.Common.Utils.AliasGenerator)
0000000005a6d9b0 000007fe2b9df8cd System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Objects.MergeOption>)
0000000005a6db00 000007fe3394ce5c System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].GetResults(System.Nullable`1<System.Data.Objects.MergeOption>)
0000000005a6db60 000007fe3394cd43 System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
0000000005a6dbc0 000007fe41eb6645 
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\System.Core.pdb\F0392B6A92EB48AABA178F73FAE390841\System.Core.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\System.Core.pdb\F0392B6A92EB48AABA178F73FAE390841\System.Core.pdb already cached

DBGHELP: System_Core - public symbols  
        C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\System.Core.pdb\F0392B6A92EB48AABA178F73FAE390841\System.Core.pdb
System.Linq.Enumerable+<UnionIterator>d__88`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]].MoveNext()
0000000005a6dc20 000007fe89113ed8 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib]]..ctor(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Int32>)
0000000005a6dc80 000007fe33837228 System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[[System.Int32, mscorlib]](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Int32>)
0000000005a6dcc0 000007fe41eb127c 
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\SysData.Business.pdb\80279CEA7E444BCC81ADCA5E07EDD4831\SysData.Business.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  File: SysData.Business.pdb

SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Get File Path: /download/symbols/SysData.Business.pdb/80279CEA7E444BCC81ADCA5E07EDD4831/SysData.Business.pdb

SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.

SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Get File Path: /download/symbols/SysData.Business.pdb/80279CEA7E444BCC81ADCA5E07EDD4831/file.ptr

SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/SysData.Business.pdb/80279CEA7E444BCC81ADCA5E07EDD4831/SysData.Business.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\SysData.Business.pdb\80279CEA7E444BCC81ADCA5E07EDD4831\SysData.Business.pdb not found
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for SysData.Business.dll
DBGHELP: SysData_Business - no symbols loaded
SysData.Business.DataCollector.PolicyExectuor.GetPolicySets(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Int32>)
0000000005a6e050 000007fe3a17d05c SysData.Business.DataCollector.PolicyExectuor.GetLinks(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Int32>)
0000000005a6e0f0 000007fe3a17aed3 SysData.Business.DataCollector.PolicyExectuor`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib],[System.Guid, mscorlib]].RunPolicy(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Int32>)
0000000005a6e2c0 000007fe3a17a453 SysData.Business.DataCollector.PolicyExectuor.RunPolicy()
0000000005a6e350 000007fe3a179f7c SysData.Business.DataCollector.RunPolicies()
0000000005a6e3b0 000007fe3a179c1f SysData.Business.DataCollector.ProcessDatapoint()
0000000005a6e440 000007fe890639a5 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
0000000005a6e5a0 000007fe89063719 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
0000000005a6e5d0 000007fe8910be92 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
0000000005a6e660 000007fe8910bc7e System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
0000000005a6e6d0 000007fe89092143 System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
0000000005a6e720 000007fe8909136a System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
0000000005a6ec88 000007fe8a25a7f3 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 0000000005a6ec88] 
0000000005a6ee18 000007fe8a25a7f3 [ContextTransitionFrame: 0000000005a6ee18] 
0000000005a6f038 000007fe8a25a7f3 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 0000000005a6f038]
```

Comment: That is a .NET program, you won't get debugging info for the ngen-ed framework assemblies.   Use the [SOS debugger extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant When I use !clrstack, then I do get stack trace of managed code, however, that managed code calls some native stuff. I want to see those native calls. Is it not possible to do that?

Comment: I don't see any overwhelming evidence, post the managed stack trace.

Comment: @HansPassant added managed stack in the question above

Comment: It is [located here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Query/InternalTrees/RuleProcessor.cs,e320bfd46f65101f), no native stuff anywhere close.

Comment: @HansPassant hmmm, you caught it right. not sure how can i mark your response as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k` displays the native part of the call stack only. This does not resolve those parts of .NET which are JIT-compiled on the fly. To see the .NET callstack, use `!clrstack` of the SOS extension.

To see both, .NET and native call stack, use the `!mk` (remember as "managed" `k`) from [SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/default.aspx). Another option is `!dumpstack` of SOS, but that's less readable.